# How to change a value of an excel field from a query

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to change a value of a field when exporting to excel in php e.g. if approved = 1 then set the text to yes and if approved = 0 then set the text to no.

I am querying the database and getting the correct value (I have tested this multiple times) , I want to change that value to a YES or NO

```
$db->query("SELECT approved FROM items, inv WHERE invInId = iniId AND ivId = iniIvId as approved");
```

The above will return 1 or 0 depending the case, now the **issue** seems to be when I am doing the following

```
if($approved == 1) {
    $val = "Yes";
} else {
    $val = "No";
}

$row_array[] = $val;

break;
```

with the above the values of the columns approved in the excel will all be "No" and if I don't use the above they will be 1 or 0 and I am not quite sure why the 1 values are not yes when I use that if statement.

full code

```
$db = new DB;
$excel = new excel;

// Set properties
$excel->set_properties(array("Creator" => "Items Reports", "Title" => "Items Approved"));

// Set headers
$headers_array = array(
    "Item Approved"
);

$excel->set_headings($headers_array);
$db->query("SELECT approved FROM items, inv WHERE invInId = iniId AND ivId = iniIvId as approved");

while ($db->next_record(0, 1)) {
    $row_array = array();
    
    for ($col = 0; $col < count($db->Record) + 1; $col++) {
        $val = "";

        switch ($col) {

            case 0:

                if($approved == 1) {
                    $val = "Yes";
                } else {
                    $val = "No";
                }

                $row_array[] = $val;

                break;

            default:            
             
                $row_array[] = $db->Record[$col];

                break;
        }
    }

    // Set row
    $excel->set_row($row_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured a solution to this, I added and if statment inside the query and it seems to be working fine now, still don't quite understand why it didn't work before but the below fixes it.

```
$db->query("SELECT IF(approved=1, 'YES', 'NO') FROM items, inv WHERE invInId = iniId AND ivId = iniIvId as approved");
```